# How to save a bitmap in and share from cache?

Tags: java, android, caching, bitmap, uri

I have a method that shares bitmap from the app with 3rd party social media apps.  I am *trying* to save my bitmap to the cache folder and share it from there.  This is my method:

```
public void shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String path = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my Meme");
    getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Meme!"));

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The Cache drive is: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The method gets the bitmap from another method through its parameters.  I want to know how to incorporate the `shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap)` parameters with the above code.

**UPDATE**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.omar.memegenerator">

    ...

    <application
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.omar.memegenerator.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The new `shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap)` method:

```
    public void shareMeme(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String path = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path + "/Memes/" + timeStamp + counter + ".jpg");
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.omar.memegenerator.fileprovider", file);
    try {
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my Meme");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Meme!"));

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The Cache drive is: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
2019-04-09 05:08:51.324 19288-19288/com.example.omar.memegenerator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.omar.memegenerator, PID: 19288
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.omar.memegenerator/cache/Memes/201904090.jpg
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at com.example.omar.memegenerator.TopImageFragment.shareMeme(TopImageFragment.java:232)
        at com.example.omar.memegenerator.TopImageFragment$6.onReceive(TopImageFragment.java:303)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Use `compress()` on `Bitmap` to save it to a file in `getCacheDir()`

Step #2: Add `FileProvider` to your project, configured to serve files from `getCacheDir()`

Step #3: Use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, instead of your existing code, to get a `Uri` to put in `EXTRA_STREAM`

Step #4: Add `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` before calling `startActivity()`, so the recipient has rights to access your content

Comment: Step 2 is already done.  I've adjusted my manifest and added the `res/xml/filespath.xml`.  But idk what you mean by "configured to serve files from `getCacheDir()`?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: " But idk what you mean by "configured to serve files from getCacheDir()?" -- `res/xml/filespath.xml` needs to [have a `<cache-path>` entry](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider?hl=en#SpecifyFiles). Also, `file` has to point to the file for your saved bitmap, and your current code has it pointing to `getCacheDir()` itself.

Comment: This is what I have in the `filespath.xml`:  

`<cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>`

How do I point the file to the bitmap?

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: Choose a filename. Create a `File` object pointing to that filename inside of `getCacheDir()`. Create a `FileOutputStream` on it and use that for `compress()`. And pass that `File` to `getUriForFile()`.

Comment: Hi.  If you could check the update, I've posted an updated method and the stack trace.  I was trying to declare a file with the path but it through an error.

Comment: @AndrosAdrianopolos: According to an earlier comment, you have `<cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>`. This serves files from an `images/` subdirectory under `getCacheDir()`. That is not where your file is. It is in a `Memes/` directory under `getCacheDir()`. Those need to match.

Comment: I did and that stopped the crash.  But now when I try to share the meme, nothing shows up on Facebook, Twitter, etc.